# Can a package name variable be passed into Android source code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is normally how one structures Android code for declaring the package and importing:

```
package com.company.myApp

import com.company.myApp.SomeClass
import com.company.myApp.somePackage.SomeOtherClass
```

Is there any way of using Android Studio/Java/whatever to pass a "compile-time" variable or pragma to effectively pass in the "com.company.myApp" string to the source code? Something like:

```
package BASE_PACKAGE_NAME

import BASE_PACKAGE_NAME.SomeClass
import BASE_PACKAGE_NAME.somePackage.SomeOtherClass
```

Comment: maybe a Java class writer could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i personally don't know anything that would do the job for you 
but as i read in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

> The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is
>   the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play
>   store, is the "application id".
>
> The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class,
>   and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations, continues
>   to be called the "package".

You can specify the application id in your gradle file as follows:

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

> Here comes the critical part: When you've done the above, the two
>   packages are independent. You are completely free to refactor your
>   code - changing the internal package used for your activities and
>   services, updating your Manifest package, and refactoring your import
>   statements. This will have no bearing on the final id of your
>   application, which is now always going to be the applicationId
>   specified in the Gradle file.
>
> You can vary the applicationId of your app for flavors and build types
>   by using the following Gradle DSL methods:

app/build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
    }
    free {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
....
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Its a bit more complex a way of achieving what I want to do but should work.