# How can I store a string to a variable for different files in Android Studio project?

Tags: android

The following code cmes from a android studio project.

I find the string `com.hicalc.soundrecorder` occurs many positions in different files repeatly.

How can I use a  variable to store the `string com.hicalc.soundrecorder`?  so I can use it everywhere.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
    flavorDimensions "default"
    namespace 'com.hicalc.soundrecorder'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hicalc.soundrecorder"
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.hicalc.soundrecorder"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "com.hicalc.soundrecorder.pro"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**utility.kt**

```
package com.hicalc.soundrecorder.data.utility

import com.hicalc.soundrecorder.R
...
```

**ui.Kt**

```
package com.hicalc.soundrecorder.presentation

import com.hicalc.soundrecorder.R
...
```

Comment: Those are the package name - have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951303/can-a-package-name-variable-be-passed-into-android-source-code) for a similar question. Short answer is no, it's not possible to replace all of them with some variable unless you wrote your own pre-processor or something.